# PostgreSQL AFTER INSERT trigger, and referencing the inserted row

Tags: postgresql, triggers, cursor

I have an INSERT trigger in PostgreSQL that I'm trying to have join the inserted row on another table, and then insert the result in a third table. Let's call the original table, that the INSERT trigger fires on, "A"; the table the cursor joins A on "B"; and the table the trigger function then inserts to "C".

My thinking was that an AFTER INSERT function should allow me to pass a value from the "NEW" row as a parameter in order to reference its corresponding row in Table A, like this:

```
myCursor CURSOR (insertedKey A.key%TYPE) FOR
  SELECT *
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B
    ON A.key=B.key
  WHERE A.key=insertedKey;

...

OPEN myCursor (NEW.key);
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO row_C;
INSERT INTO C VALUES (row_C.*);
```

This gives me an empty cursor. If I trigger the trigger on AFTER UPDATE, it works, but with the old row from A. This leads me to think that PostgreSQL doesn't think AFTER INSERT/UPDATE means what I think it means.

Or maybe I'm just doing something wrong? Is there any way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why it happens but you could do something along the line of

```
INSERT INTO C
  SELECT NEW.*, B.*
    FROM B
    WHERE B.key = NEW.key
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. It also seems to let me pass the entire NEW row as a cursor parameter.